# I'm implementing handsontable, where i need show the excel data in handsontable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I need to show the data in handsontable from excle sheet, But I got struck up in the middle, any one please help me here.

My controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult GetJsonData(FormCollection formCollection)   
{
    var usersList = new List<User>();
    if (Request != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
        if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) &&      !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
        {
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
            {
                var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                {
                    var user = new User();
                    user.FirstName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
                    user.LastName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
                    usersList.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }
    }       
    return View("GetJsonData",usersList);
}
```

Index view

```
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetJsonData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>File:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="btnsave" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}  

<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htColumnHeaders"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnsave').click(function () {
        var url = '/Home/GetJsonData';
        $.get(url,
            null,
            function (data) {
                debugger;
                var container = document.getElementById('#example1');
                var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                    data: data,
                    rowheader: true,
                    colheader: true
                });

            });
    });
</script>
```

GetJsonData view

```
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htColumnHeaders"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '/Home/GetJsonData';
        $.get(url,
            null,
            function (data) {
                  var container = document.getElementById('#example1');
                var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                    data: data,
                    rowheader: true,
                    colheader: true
                });
                debugger;
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: i'm getting null value in handsontable,

Comment: In which line of code. You need to explain the issue.

Comment: if i change the return type has json here i can see the jsondata in view return View("GetJsonData",usersList)  But same is not coming the jquery

Answer (score 0):

have resolved this issue.

```
    function UploadExcel() {

        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("Uplaod").files.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = document.getElementById("Uplaod").files[i];

            formData.append("Document", file);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url:"/Home/UpoadFile",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //data: JSON.stringify(oInvoice),
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //async: false,
            success: function (result) {

                debugger;
                if (result != null)
                {
                    //var data2 = result,
                    //    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
                    //    hot1;
                    //hot1 = new Handsontable(container, {
                    //    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data2))
                    //});
                    //document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                        var data = result,
                           example1 = document.getElementById('example1'),
                            settings1,
                            emailValidator;

                        emailValidator = '^[^@@\\s]+@@([^@@\\s]+\\.)+[^@@\\s]+$';
                        emailValidator=function(value,callback)
                        {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                if (/.+@@.+/.test(value)) {
                                    callback(true);
                                }
                                else {
                                    callback(false);
                                }
                            }, 10);
                        }

                        settings1={
                            data: data,
                            colHeaders: ['FirstName','LastName','Email'],
                            columns:[
                                {data:'FirstName'},
                                {data:'LastName'},
                                { data: 'Email', validator: emailValidator, allowInvalid: false }

                            ]
                        } ;
                        var hot = new Handsontable(example1, settings1);

                        //function bindDumpButton()
                        //{
                        //    if (typeof Handsontable === "undefined") {
                        //        return;
                        //    }

                        //    //Handsontable.Dom.AddEvent(document.body, 'click', function (e) {
                        //    //    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

                        //    //    if (element.nodeName == "BUTTON" && element.name == 'dump') {
                        //    //        var name = element.getAttribute('data-dump');
                        //    //        var instance = element.getAttribute('data-instance');
                        //    //        var hot = window[instance];
                        //    //        console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
                        //    //    }
                        //    //});

                        //}
                        //bindDumpButton();
                   // });
                        }

                else {


                    // alert("Something Seems wrong. try agin afterwards");
                }

            },
            error: function (err) {

            }
        });
    }
```